Always save using writable database
I have a rails app which connects to a primary database and its replica, i.e. ApplicationRecord says
connects_to database: {writing: :primary, reading: :primary_replica}

Is there any reason I shouldn't also add this?
around_save :ensure_primary_database
around_destroy :ensure_primary_database

def ensure_primary_database
  ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to role: :writing do
    yield
  end
end

It seems to work, but does look like it forces a transaction (like all activerecord callbacks I guess). I'm just wondering why this isn't something Rails automatically infers, and therefore if it's such a good idea for me to do this?
The automatic role-switching middleware does work for the most part, but there are cases where some Devise modules, for example, will trigger a write during a GET request.

Not clear what problem you are trying to solve , but instead of doing this generally for all models, I’d identify which models always require the primary database and use a separate base class to always connect them to it.
